# Flask-WTF 'FileField' object has no attribute 'has_file'

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms, flask-uploads

I combine **Flask-WTF** and **Flask-upload** to handle file upload on my App.

My package versions are:

```
Flask-Uploads==0.2.1
Flask-WTF==0.11
WTForms==2.1
```

Here is the snippet of my code:

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from flask_wtf.file import FileAllowed, FileRequired
from wtforms.fields import (StringField, SubmitField, FileField)
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length
from app import photos

class AddCourseForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Course name', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(1, 100)])
    image = FileField('image', validators=[FileRequired(), FileAllowed(photos, 'Images only!')])
    submit = SubmitField('Add course')
```

And here is the snippet of the upload code:

```
@operator.route('/add-course', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_course():
    form = AddCourseForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        course_name = form.name.data
        filename = photos.save(request.files['image'], name="courses/" + course_name + "_course.")
        course = Course(name=course_name, image=filename)
        db.session.add(course)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Successfully added {} '.format(course.course_name()) + 'course', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('operator.courses'))
    return render_template('main/operator/add_course.html', form=form)
```

But, when I submitted that, I got this following error:

```
AttributeError: 'FileField' object has no attribute 'has_file'
```

Then I tried to following this [documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/form.html#validation), without Flask-Upload by passing the extensions directly:

```
image = FileField('image', validators=[FileRequired(), FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'], 'Images only!')])
```

But I still got the same error.

So, what's wrong with my code..?
Please, any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

You import `FileField` from the wtforms library:

```py
from wtforms.fields import (StringField, SubmitField, FileField)
```

... but the `FileField.has_file()` method is specific to `Flask-WTF`.

You need to add `FileField` to the other imports from `flask_wtf.file`.

You can access the API documentation of `Flask-WTF.file.FileField` [here](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_wtf.file.FileField).

The current implementation ([found here](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/master/flask_wtf/file.py#L11)) is:

```py
class FileField(_FileField):
    """Werkzeug-aware subclass of :class:`wtforms.fields.FileField`."""

    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        valuelist = (x for x in valuelist if isinstance(x, FileStorage) and x)
        data = next(valuelist, None)

        if data is not None:
            self.data = data
        else:
            self.raw_data = ()

    def has_file(self):
        """Return ``True`` if ``self.data`` is a
        :class:`~werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage` object.
        .. deprecated:: 0.14.1
            ``data`` is no longer set if the input is not a non-empty
            ``FileStorage``. Check ``form.data is not None`` instead.
        """

        warnings.warn(FlaskWTFDeprecationWarning(
            '"has_file" is deprecated and will be removed in 1.0. The data is '
            'checked during processing instead.'
        ))
        return bool(self.data)
```

As you can see, the class inherits from the standard wtforms implementation (named `_FileField` in the module) but extends it to override the `process_formdata()` method and add the `has_file()` method.

Also note that they are depreciating the method and suggest that you just check the `data` attribute of the field instead - its not exactly a technical implementation so you can just do what they do to get the same functionality: `bool(field.data)`.

For reference, here is the wtforms `FileField` implementation:

```py
class FileField(Field):
    """Renders a file upload field.
    By default, the value will be the filename sent in the form data.
    WTForms **does not** deal with frameworks' file handling capabilities.
    A WTForms extension for a framework may replace the filename value
    with an object representing the uploaded data.
    """

    widget = widgets.FileInput()

    def _value(self):
        # browser ignores value of file input for security
        return False
```

...which shows that it doesn't have any methods beyond those defined on the base `Field` class.